# Convert Collection<Integer> to Spliterator.OfInt

Tags: java, java-stream

How can `Collection<Integer>` be converted to `Spliterator.OfInt`? I have tried alot of ways but didn't work out. I can do :

```
Collection<Integer> coll = new ArrayList<>();
Spliterator<Integer> ints = coll.spliterator();
```

but I want a `Spliterator.OfInt` instead of `Spliterator<Integer>`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `Stream<Integer>` from `.stream()` and then `mapToInt` to get `IntStream` and finally invoke `spliterator` to get `Spliterator.OfInt`:

```
Spliterator.OfInt ofInt = coll.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).spliterator();
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to supply the unboxing operation, so something like this would work:

```java
Collection<Integer> coll = ...

Spliterator.OfInt spliterator = coll.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).spliterator();
```

Comment: What is the difference in your and above answer?

Comment: I don't personally feel like it would have any drastic effect on performance. I mean looking at the above code, it is smaller.

Comment: @Somebody I never claimed that this is faster (runtime performance), just that it generates less code, since it doesn't have to create a hidden method. Also, using `stream()` was a less code than using `StreamSupport`, which is what the other question *was* doing, but it's been updated to do what I did. --- So, yes, as the two answers currently stand, `i -> i` is less code to *write* than `Integer::intValue` (11 characters less), but it causes the compiler to *generate* more bytecode.

Comment: Sometimes, it's worth spelling out explicitly what will happen. When there is an actual operation that should not be distracted from, auto(un)boxing is a great tool. But when you have a lambda expression like `i -> i` whose only purpose is to perform the hidden `intValue()` call, which readers have to determine from the context, i.e. `mapToInt`, an explicit method reference like `Integer::intValue` may be easier to read.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me. When you do `mapToInt` on a `Stream<?>`, *it means that it would be an unboxing operation* because you can not return anything except an `int` @Holger So `i -> i` is better than `Integer::intValue` because `i -> i` uses less characters `11`. Why worry about `11` characters? Because people are worried about: *just that it generates less code* ;)

Comment: @roundAbout you have it backwards. When you see `i -> i`, you first have to look around to recognize that its context is `mapToInt`, to understand that it does more than, e.g. an `i -> i` in a context where a `Function` is expected. In fact, when a `Function` is expected, I prefer using `Function.identity()` to document that just passing the parameter is intentional. And it will save a few hundred bytes at runtime which trumps the few characters at typing, if we really talk about such irrelevant savings…I hope, you know that `Integer::intValue` generates less code than `i -> i` in this context